# tcpdump socket type not supported

Tags: ubuntu, tcpdump

I'm having some trouble with tcpdump in Ubuntu. I have installed Wireshark and tcpdump with no problems and can't seem to capture traffic.

[image: here is the source]

Comment: You’re using WSL. This is obviously not going to work. Why not just use the Windows version of Wireshark?